# Vim how to set directory used for colorschemes

Tags: vim

By default, Vim looks for colorschemes in the `<runtimepath>/colors/` directory.

Is there a way to specify a different directory name, or to specify an additional directory that vim can in look for colorschemes?

The purpose of wanting additional directories is for organizing colorschemes from third-party sources.

Comment: You *can* do it on your own by setting `runtimepath` dynamically but that's probably too complex for your limited "needs". You should look into "runtimepath managers" like Pathogen or "plugin managers" like vim-plug.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`'runtimepath'` actually is a comma-separated list of directories. Each of those can contain the common structure of `plugin`, `autoload`, `colors`, etc. Vim is considering *all* of those trees for its configuration.

So, to separate third-party colorschemes, you can put them in `~/.vimstyles/colors/` instead of `~/.vim/colors`, and augment the runtimepath in your `~/.vimrc`:

```
:set runtimepath+=~/.vimstyles
```

#### Package management

If your requirement actually is having a separate directory structure for each colorscheme (or more general: plugin), Vim 8 provides a built-in way for that: `:help packages`. These are directores below `~/.vim/pack/` that are *automatically* added to the runtimepath. [pathogen.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2332) has been offering something similar also for older Vim versions.

[*Plugin managers*](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Plugin-manager) build on top of that and enable features like automatic updating from various sources, dependency management, and so on.